# Mutual Friends of Friends Neo4j Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new in Neo4j and Cypher and writing on my BA-Thesis in which I compare a RDBMS against Neo4j Graph Database in case of social networks. I´ve defined some queries in SQL and Cypher for a Performance Test over JDBC and REST API in JMETER. However, I have a problem declaring the Cypher query to get the Nodes which are the mutual friends of friends for a certain Node.

My first approach was like so:

```
MATCH (me:Enthusiast {Id: 488})-[:abonniert]->(f:Enthusiast)-[:abonniert]->(fof:Enthusiast)<-[:abonniert]-(f) RETURN o
```

Comment: Could you please add details on your question ? Right now, it's difficult to say what're you're asking.

Comment: If a NODE XY has two or more friends who have (partially) mutual friends then i want to return those information. So I don´t want to search mutual friends on the first degree but in the second degree. hope you understand it

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're pretty close with your Cypher statement. I assume that "mutual friend on 2nd degree" means that I'm mutual friend with someone the target is mutual friend as well?

If so (shortening labels and relationship types for readbility):

```
MATCH 
(me:En {Id: 488})-[:abonniert]->(f:En)-[:abonniert]->(fof:En),
(fof)-[:abonniert]->(f)-[:abonniert]->me
RETURN fof
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your effort, but i think you understand me wrong. Imagine i am the node with the id 488. I want to know which of my friends have mutual friends.

Answer (score 1):

it would be nice if you can create an example scenario at http://console.neo4j.org/ .
i would also omit the relationships direction.

```
MATCH (me:Enthusiast {Id: 488})-[:abonniert]->(f:Enthusiast),
(f)-[:abonniert]-(x:Enthusiast)-[:aboniert]-(y:Enthusiast)
WHERE f--y AND Id(y) <> 488
RETURN f, y, count(x) as NrMutFr
```

**edit**

try this console query, works for the scenario: http://console.neo4j.org/r/tws07k

my above query would in that case be

```
MATCH (me:Enthusiast {Id: 488})-[:abonniert]->(f:Enthusiast),
(f)-[:abonniert]->(x:Enthusiast)<-[:aboniert]-(y:Enthusiast)
WHERE me--y 
RETURN f, y, count(x) as NrMutFr
```

the difference between your posted question query is that you must finish the last node with a new substitute `y` and not `f`. than also, if necessary, again match that `y` with starting `me` node

Comment: Hey, here you are http://console.neo4j.org/r/pl3m0g ... the target is to generate a recommendation of potential subscription for the node 488. The Return value must be in this case the Node with the Id: 210... the direction of the relationship is important i think because it isn´t a friendship ..

Answer (score 0):

Once you've matched your friends you should be able to express the rest of the query as a path predicate: match "my friends", filter out everyone except "those of my friends who have some friend in common", which amounts to the same as "those of my friends who have a friend-of-friend who is a friend of mine.

```
MATCH (me:Enthusiast { Id: 488 })-[:abonniert]->(f)
WHERE f-[:abonniert]-()-[:abonniert]-()<-[:abonniert]-me
RETURN f
```

Here's a console: http://console.neo4j.org/r/87n0j9. If I have misunderstood your question you can make changes in that console, click "share" and post back the link here with an explanation of what result you expect to get back.

**Edit**
If you want to get the nodes that are two or more of your friends are related to in common, you can do

```
MATCH (me:Enthusiast { Id: 488 })-[:subscribed]->(f)-[:subscribed]->(common) 
WITH common, count(common) AS cnt 
WHERE cnt > 1 
RETURN common
```

A node that is a common neighbour of your neighbours can be described as a node you can reach on at least two paths. You can therefore match your neighbour-of-neighbours, count the times each "non" is matched, and if it is matched more than once then it is a "non" that is common to at least two of your neighbours. If you want you can return that count and order the result by it as a type of scoring (since this seems to be for recommendation purposes).

```
MATCH (me:Enthusiast { Id: 488 })-[:subscribed]->(f)-[:subscribed]->(common) 
WITH common, count(common) AS score 
WHERE score > 1 
RETURN common, score
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Comment: i already commented below @ulkas answer .. look at that console console.neo4j.org/r/pl3m0g .. i want to get the node 210 because it is a common subscription of my(node 488) subscriptions which is not my subscription yet.. thx

Comment: Well "to know which of my friends have mutual friends" is not the same as knowing those mutual friends. I'll add how to do that to my answer then.